# Fabric cannot import paramiko

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko

I've installed paramiko and when I import it in python, it works normally, but I get the following error running fabric:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 24, in <module>
    import paramiko as ssh
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

what can I do?

Comment: What does `python --version` print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether `fab` uses the same python executable that you used to install `paramiko`.

fab:

```
$ head -1 `which fab`
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Check python executable path using `which` or `type`:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ type python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

If you used `pip`, you may need to also check `pip`:

```
$ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```